# Google Sheet Apps Script - Hide rows by one cell's contents, excluding completely empty rows

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I make sure that the row being worked on in the below doesn't have the cellvalue portion executed if the row is empty (tried to make that work with `rowvalue.some(!isblank())` but it doesn't skip the cellvalue portion regardless of whether it hits a blank line or not)?

```
function onEdit(){
  for( i=7 ; i<=lastRow ; i++) // Start beyond header rows
  {
    var rowvalue = sheet.getRange(i,1,1,36).getValues();
    if (rowvalue.some(!isblank()))
    {
      var cellvalue = sheet.getRange("K"+i).getValue();
      if (cellvalue != "-")
      {
        sheet.hideRows(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: isBlank() is a range method

Comment: @Tanaike You have good grammar, and no spelling mistakes, for someone with poor English skill. Your other answers are also well written. I am not sure why you would write what you prior did. If it wasn't understable, you could have just said that.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `You have good grammar, and no spelling mistakes, for someone with poor English skill. Your other answers are also well written. I am not sure why you would write what you prior did. If it wasn't understable, you could have just said that.`, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your expected result, I would like to try to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot understand your question soon.

Comment: @cooper Thanks! I think what you are saying is I can skip .some, and isblank will work on the entire array by itself. Will check that shortly.

Comment: @Tanaike Better?

Comment: Actually I  was  just pointing out that isBlank() is not a standalone function it is a method of the range class. Unless you wrote an isBlank of your own which you did not provide.

Comment: @Cooper No isBlank function of my own. Any chance of an answer that corrects my issue, as what I thought you were saying also doesn't work in the above script?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Main sticking point is forgetting, somehow, that Javascript is case sensitive. But this is the relevant changed lines of the logic that worked as well.

```
var rowsvalue = sheet.getRange(i,1,1,lastColumn)
if(!rowsvalue.isBlank())
```